# Interaction Studio APIs

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm looking for Interaction Studio API documentation. What I'm trying to achieve is to create an email which will call API to get the next best actions recommended by Interaction Studio. Thank you for any reference or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to make this happen:

1. Create a Touchpoint for email interaction
2. Configure NBA in interaction studio under that TouchPpint
3. Call interaction API from email to retrieve the NBA image using POST (as per documentation below)
4. Interaction studio will return NBA based on eligibility and priority rules

The Interaction Studio API documentation can be found here: https://na5.thunderhead.com/one/help/interaction-studio/technical-documents/one-api/one_api_interaction/

The request body would look like this:

{
"customerKey": "abc@abc.com",
"customerKeyName": "customerkey",
"properties": [],
"uri": "assisted://salesforcecore/nba"
}

The optimisation point should be called "nba" in IS for this to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you @c-carswell. This is exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much documentation for [Interaction Studio API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_is_configure_is_api_event.htm&type=5). You can start here: [Interaction Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_is_interaction_studio.htm&type=5).

It sounds like what you're trying to achieve can be done through the Journey Builder API by [Admitting Contacts via API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_admit_contacts_via_api.htm&type=5) which is essentially using the API entry event within Journey Builder.

Comment: Hi Jackson, thank you for the response. I'm actually looking for something bit different. IS can change content on your website for each user based on their behavior. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the same recommended content via API and use it in emails so the users have constant experience across all channels.